# Application Load balancer for Service Segmentation Using Subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Currently, I am doing service segmentation using subdomains in an existing application.

For example:

```
www.example.com -> static website delivered from s3
admin.example.com -> ELB1 to ec2 group 1
accounts.example.com -> ELB2 to ec2 group 2
search.example.com -> ELB3 to ec2 group 3
```

You can see that I need 3 ELB to achieve this. With the new Application load balancer, I am hoping to do this on 1 load balancer using routing rules.

For example :

```
www.example.com -> static website delivered from s3
admin.example.com -> ELB1 to ec2 group 1
accounts.example.com -> ELB1 to ec2 group 2
search.example.com -> ELB1 to ec2 group 3
```

I cannot rewrite my application to do this. I am hoping to achieve this with routing rules on the application load balancer.

I am aware that I can specify rules for the part after the domain. Can I specify rules for the subdomain?

Already read:
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx3RG2S7V2LM4Y2/Introducing-Application-Load-Balancer-Unlocking-and-Optimizing-Architectures

Comment: As of October 2016, the answer is no. I don't think they will support this anytime soon (Maybe never as this will reduce number ELBs required for existing applications). Also, this will force us to use same domain, which is expected to perform better on HTTP 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS recently added support for Host-based routing to Application Load Balancers:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-host-based-routing-and-increased-rules-on-its-application-load-balancer/

Comment: See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), Link only answers are not ideal "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: Thanks for the update I was waiting for this from the day they launched application load balancer  :-)

Answer (score 0):

We had this question too and it appears there's no way as of now.  We have several non Production environments that all use subdomains so we didn't want to create 30+ ELBs.  We ended up using NGINX as a proxy in the non Production environments, but the tradeoff was that we had to have another EC2 instance.